# C#/Windows Forms. События для динамических кнопок

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть форма в программа, в которой выводится товары подгружаемые с бд. Возник вопрос как можно понять на какую кнопку нажимаю? т.е. для первого товара или же для пятого.

Comment: `var button = (Button)sender;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться свойством `Tag`.

Тогда создавая динамически `NumericUpDown` будем запоминать в это свойство Id товара

```
NumericUpDown numeric = new NumericUpDown
{
    Name = "numeric" + (item as Product).Id,
    Tag = (item as Product).Id,
    Top = top,
    Left = left,
    Minimum = 0,
    Maximum = 1000
};
numeric.ValueChanged += Numeric_ValueChanged;
numeric.DataBindings.Add("Value", item, "Amount");
```

Тогда в обработчике изменения значения в NumericUpDown можно сделать так

```
private void Numeric_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var numeric = sender as NumericUpDown;
    if (numeric == null) return;

    //ищем по Id в Tag нужный товар
    var nameProduct = _bsProducts
                                .OfType<Product>()
                                .First(p => p.Id == (int)numeric.Tag);

    _message = $"Количество изменено у: {nameProduct.Name} на {numeric.Value}";
}
```

[image: пример работы]

Пример можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/YyaB_DIA3W5Vui)